# No module named 'keras.wrappers'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have this code on google colab which allows me to optimise an LSTM model using gridsearchCV, but recently an error message has appeared:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.wrappers'.

is there another module other than 'keras.wrappers' that allows the code to be restarted?

Code:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
from keras import optimizers

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor

def create_model(unit, dropout_rate, lr ):
 model=Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(unit,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,5)))
 model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
 model.add(LSTM(unit))
 model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
 model.add(Dense(1))
 adam= optimizers.Adam(lr)
 model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mean_squared_error')

 return model

my_regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=2)

grid_param_LSTM = {
    'unit':   [50, 70, 120],
    'batch_size': [12, 24, 48],
    'epochs': [200],
    'lr': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
    'dropout_rate':[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
}

grid_GBR = GridSearchCV(estimator=my_regressor, param_grid = grid_param_LSTM, scoring = 'neg_root_mean_squared_error',  cv = 2)
grid_GBR.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_GBR.best_score_, grid_GBR.best_params_))
```

Comment: It was working before and now it has stopped? Maybe it's just a colab problem and stopping running the vm and rebooting it all works: `Runtime` > `Restart runtime` > confirm `Yes`

Comment: Yes, it used to work. I've tried your solution but the problem persists. Could it be a python update that is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes it could, but also a keras update.. try to install a new version of keras by running the following in a colab cell `!pip install keras==specific-version`; change `specific_version` with a previous one

Comment: I had the first version of Keras 2.13.1. I updated it but I still have the problem.

Comment: Try to install the version `2.12` or `2.11`. They should be quick trials

Comment: Your idea of installing Keras with an earlier version worked well, but for the code to work in its entirety you also need to install tenseflow in a version that is just as suitable (2.12 for example). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This works for me**

```
pip install keras==2.12.0
```

Another Approach you can try

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem and I solved adding above import an instruction to install scikeras has KerasClassifier

[image]

!pip install scikeras

from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please insert code as text, not as image. You can highlight it as such using the appropriate field in the editor.

Comment: !pip install scikeras

from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

Comment: Use of the exclamation point in conjunction with install commands is outdated and you should be suggesting the magic variations `%pip install scikeras`

Answer (score 2):

Rename reference and grid parameter. Note the prefix "model__"

instead of using:

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
```

use:

```
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
```

the example below works fine for me, using keras 2.14.0

```
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Function to create the Keras model for SciKeras
def create_model(optimizer='adam', lstm_neurons=50, activation='relu'):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(lstm_neurons, activation=activation, input_shape=(seq_len, features)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')
    return model

# Keras model with SciKeras wrapper
model = KerasRegressor(model=create_model, epochs=25, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

# Hyperparameters to be optimized
param_grid = {
    #'model__optimizer': ['adam'],      # Note the prefix "model__"
    'model__lstm_neurons': [10, 25 , 50 , 100],         # Note the prefix "model__"
    'model__activation': ['relu', 'sigmoid'],        # Note the prefix "model__"
    'batch_size': [1],
    'epochs': [10]
}

# GridSearchCV
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=3, verbose=2)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Display the best hyperparameters
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

# Extract results from GridSearchCV
results = pd.DataFrame(grid_result.cv_results_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tensorflow and keras version 2.14.0 also eliminated the error for me.
!pip install tensorflow==2.14.0 (! 'cos I wrote my code using jupyter notebook)
!pip install keras==2.14.0

Comment: This doesn't add anything compared to accepted https://stackoverflow.com/a/77285146/7264739 Of course newer versions will also work.